# Website restored from .jpa becomes corrupted after first run

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, webserver, backup

I've made a backup of Joomla website using Akeeba's backup, send the .jpa backup file to FTP server and restored it there using Akeeba Kickstart. So far no errors, no warnings.

At first run website loads correctly, but **when I hit F5 most elements are gone** probably due to Joomla's database corruption.

So it seems that running site fires up a script that doesn't only read from the database, but also modifies it in a way that keeps corrupting the following connections. I didn't include any PHP code on my own, I don't even use MySQL databases (only Postgres). It happens after restoring 2 of my Joomla websites, every time. I guess it's a server issue, since I am able to restore and view these pages on my local PC without problems.

Comment: If you can restore the website on your PC why not upload it to your server? As you say it may be caused by your server configuration. Maybe an old PHP version?

Comment: Joomla website must be restored along with Joomla'a MySQL tables and with proper access data for those - extracting from .jpa file is the "default" way for that. I doubt that PHP version is the reason, server has 5.4.

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?